# Can i mine with ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5400 Series GPU?

Tags: go-ethereum, bitcoin

i have ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5400 Series integrated gpu in my laptop can i use it for mining ?[image]

Comment: You cannot mine ether with the GPU efficiently, the current algorithm requires more than 2 GBytes of memory.

Comment: [![look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sr2hr.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sr2hr.jpg) what about me? can i ? HD 5400 too but with 2048 mb? wtf? :D

Answer (score 1):

While in theory you could participate I highly doubt you would get any money.

There are two ways to mine: solo and pool.

#### Solo

In solo you compete as a single entity with the whole network. Your chances of ever solving a block are virtually zero. Also you would likely have to run a full node here which I promise you will not be possible on your laptop.

#### Pool

In a pool you share mining capacity with a group of people and get proportional payout. While you could make some cents here in theory, I still doubt you wanna 'burn' your laptop for it.

On top of that, Ethereum has I would say the highest demands to hardware these days among all cryptos.

I suggest you look into smaller coins and maybe CPU mined coins like Monero within mining pools. Anyhow I would be surprised if that card can make any mentionable amount of money mining these days.

You can download and try [Minergate](https://minergate.com/), it runs the most profitable miner of their supported coins.

It is an easy introduction into mining but if you really want to look into int you will need to invest some money.